# How to mock promisify call on mysql query nodeJS using sinon and Mocha?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, stub

This is my code using mysql -

```
import * as mysql from 'mysql';
import {promisify} from 'util';


 const connectionParams:any = {
     /* set as environment variables */
     host: host,
     user: user,
     password: password,
     port: parseInt(port)
 };
 var connection:any;
 const getRecords = async (inputValue: string) => {

//validate inputValue

const userIds: string[] = [];
logger.info("Creating mysql connection");
try {
    connection = mysql.createConnection(connectionParams);
    const query = promisify(connection.query).bind(connection);
    const queryResult = await query({ sql: sqlQuery, timeout: 1000, values: value1, inputValue] });
    if (queryResult) {
        queryResult.forEach((row) => {
            userIds.push(row.userid);
        });
    }
} catch (error) {
    logger.info(error);
    // console.log(error);
    throw new Error('Could not retrieve user IDs');
} finally {
    connection.end();
}
return userIds;
 };
```

And this is my test -

```
it('should return a list of records when right inputs are given', async() => {
        sinon.stub(process, 'env').value({
            'database': 'TESTDB'
        });
        let dummyArray = [{ userid: 'xyz' }];
        let createConnection = {
            connect: function(connectionParams: any) {
                return Promise.resolve()
            },
            query : sinon.stub().withArgs({}).callsFake(function (...args): Promise<Object>{
                const dummyArray = [{ userid: 'xyz' }];
                return new Promise(function(resolve){resolve(dummyArray)});
            }),
            end: function() {}
        };
        let mySqlStub = {
            createConnection: sinon.stub().returns(createConnection)
        };
        const dbops = proxyquire('../../lib/dbops', {'mysql': mySqlStub}).default;
        expect(await dbops.getUserIds('Delete')).to.deep.equal(['xyz']);
    });
```

How do I write the fake function for the query?

> query : sinon.stub().withArgs({}).callsFake(function (...args):
> Promise{
> const dummyArray = [{ userid: 'xyz' }];
> return new Promise(function(resolve){resolve(dummyArray)});
> })

This does not work for me. How can I get this to work? I cannot get the stub function to resolve and return the intended value in the main function. The query just hangs and throws an error after the timeout. The error is happening in "matchingfakes" method within the stub.

Answer (score 1):

`proxyquire` is used for stubbing the standalone function exports from a module or package. Since `mysql` is an object, you can stub its methods by `sinon.stub(obj, 'method')`. You don't need to use use `proxyquire` package.

Even if you use `util.promisify` to generate promise versions for the NodeJS error-First callback method(`mysql.query(sql, callback)`, the callback signature is `function (error, results, ...args): void`). You need to use `.callsFake()` to create a mock implementation for this method, and trigger the promise version by calling its callback.

And, you should `import` the function after stubbing the environment variables. Because when you import the `./dbops` module, the code in the module scope will be executed immediately, at this time, the environment variables are not stubbed.

E.g.

`dbops.ts`:

```
import mysql from 'mysql';
import { promisify } from 'util';

const connectionParams: any = {
  host: process.env.HOST,
  user: process.env.USER,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
  port: parseInt(process.env.PORT || '3306'),
};
var connection: any;

const getRecords = async (inputValue: string) => {
  const sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM tests';
  const value1 = '';
  const userIds: string[] = [];
  console.info('Creating mysql connection');
  try {
    connection = mysql.createConnection(connectionParams);
    const query = promisify(connection.query).bind(connection);
    const queryResult = await query({ sql: sqlQuery, timeout: 1000, values: value1, inputValue });
    if (queryResult) {
      queryResult.forEach((row) => {
        userIds.push(row.userid);
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.info(error);
    throw new Error('Could not retrieve user IDs');
  } finally {
    connection.end();
  }
  return userIds;
};

export { getRecords };
```

`dbops.test.ts`:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import mysql from 'mysql';

describe('69702002', () => {
  it('should return a list of records when right inputs are given', async () => {
    sinon.stub(process, 'env').value({
      HOST: '127.0.0.1',
      USER: 'testuser',
      PASSWORD: 'testpwd',
      PORT: '3306',
    });
    const { getRecords } = await import('./dbops');
    const dummyArray = [{ userid: 'xyz' }];

    let connectionStub = {
      query: sinon.stub().callsFake((sql, callback) => {
        callback(null, dummyArray);
      }),
      end: sinon.stub(),
    };
    sinon.stub(mysql, 'createConnection').returns(connectionStub);
    const actual = await getRecords('test input');
    sinon.assert.match(actual, ['xyz']);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(mysql.createConnection, {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      user: 'testuser',
      password: 'testpwd',
      port: 3306,
    });
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(connectionStub.end);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 69702002
Creating mysql connection
    ✓ should return a list of records when right inputs are given (945ms)


  1 passing (952ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   90.48 |       50 |     100 |      90 |                   
 dbops.ts |   90.48 |       50 |     100 |      90 | 27-28             
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I apologize for not responding immediately due to work. I tried the above solution with a minor fix. It works if the method getRecords is not a default export. In my case, I have to make it a default export. I tried tweaking but it didn't work for me. If the export is not default, however, this is a working solution. I had to use mysql serverless library because of project constraints, for which I was able to stub like the solution suggested for AWS RDS.

Comment: I used your approach for pool: `const query = util.promisify(pool.query).bind(pool);`